# setting of the AWD keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

[image]When I create an emulator in the AWD manager (I use 233 & api 10) on my computer that is setup for american english, it defaults to a Japanese IME keyboard (bad choice in my opinion).  So when I try to run a simple textfield app such as...

I get the foreign keyboard. How do I change it to U.S. english?  If I go to settings in the emulator and select US english it has no effect.  It just stays Japanese IME.
Thanks, Dean

Comment: The only way I ever get into that mode is if I manually choose it. However, once in that mode, I do not see how to exit it, either from the IME itself or from Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long press a text input field (for example the one in Google Search) until a popup menu appears.

There, press "Input method" and select the one you want to use.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  The fix was also permanent as the next execution of the AWD displayed the correct keyboard.