# Android inputType="numberDecimal" brings up keyboard without commas

Tags: java, android

So i have been playing around with a little game with some mathematical questions. The application gives you, for example, a question like 23 + 47, and that's fine and all, but when it gives you a question like 9/6 the problems appears. Since you input the result in an EditText, i need the correct input type. But! when i do

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

the soft keyboard it comes up with, is a soft keyboard without seperators, which mean i can't make commas. And it pretty much ruins the game :-)
I have tried things like

`android:inputType"numberSigned|numberDecimal"`

i have also tried

`android:digits="0123456789."`
but nothing worked so far.

I just can't get the right keyboard up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

is for taking decimal inputs, so all the digits from 0 to 9 including the decimal point sign(.) only can be the input values. And it works fine. I don't understand where comma sign came into picture.

Comment: Well i though that numberDecimal meant that it would have a seperator so i could input, for example, 1.5. What shall i use then?

Comment: decimal . sign will be taken as an input so no need to worry.

Comment: I don't know what's going on. Even if numberDecimal takes . as an input, i can't get the right keyboard up for clicking . so the user can do it. The keyboard it is coming up with is this: http://imgur.com/QSRp7 and there is no decimal point.

Comment: long click on the edittext, then select android keyboard from the dialog appears after long clicking the edittext.

Comment: @user1110700 I see what your problem is - it's the very common issue that the Android Emulator default input method is Japanese. See this answer for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11730683/1249938

Comment: Thanks! I had never though of that, now everthing i working properly! :)

Answer (score 9):

Try add comma ",".  It may cause from different format of digits.

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

Comment: great...The decimal separator is the dot ('.') in English, but in French, it's the
comma (',').