# Virtual Keyboard won't write numbers on GenyMotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion but I have a problem with its virtual keyboard.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288228/android-softkeyboard-never-shows-up-in-emulator) answer in order to make the virtual keyboard appear but I have a EditText with `<android:inputType="numberDecimal">`. The virtual keyboard doesn't write numbers (it only writes them unless I write a letter before them). Spell checker is already off.

Any idea?

Comment: It maybe a little late but have you tried installing another keyboard and see what happens? I had a problem with Genymotion's soft keyboard and installed/used Go keyboard on it...