# Alloy left/right keyboard events ScrollableView

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm building a titanium alloy app and I'm using ScrollableView to show different pages of the app. I have set showPagingControl="false" and scrollingEnabled="false". Its got a basic login code so when the user is valid it goes to the next page.

I just realised that focusing the scrollableview and using keyboard left/right buttons changes the page which isn't ideal as the user isn't meant to be logged in. Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: Maby you can check if the user is logged in with the scroll event fired by the view, if he is not send him back ? Why are you using a scrollable view as page navigation ?

Comment: I did think of that but thought it was a bit of a hack. I'm using it as navigation as i like the animated transition. Feel free to point me in a better direction!

Comment: That the scrollableview still scrolls when scrollingEnabled="false" is set sounds like a bug.. You could also look into the open parameters of a window: <http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/openWindowParams> animation and transition.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug. I've been testing it in genymotion as I don't have a way to test a hardware keyboard currently. I just tried it in the android emulator and it seems fine.

Comment: also to [enable hardware keyboard genymotion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288703/3419997)

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking this as resolved as I think it was an error in my emulator