# Android Studio: KeyboardLayout not displaying on Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I am running below code(as in screenshot).However am not getting "text" keyboard layout upon running the emulator ie.,placing the cursor over the Edittext in the emulator.

[image]

Please help with this.

Thanks & Regards,
Subin Alex

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288228/android-softkeyboard-never-shows-up-in-emulator) solution...

Answer (score 0):

See this image :

Click first

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

check this box:

[image]
Cool -:)